# How to interface a Powerpoint presentation and customize each slide with different gestures.?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, leap-motion

SOS! 
I have a hyperlinked Powerpoint with some pictures on each slide. Selecting each picture with a certain gesture, it will jump to the next slide hyperlinked to this particular pic. I would want to know how to interface this ppt i have with my C# code. and write a code for each slide.

I have written a simple code to detect swipe gestures and key tap. These are the two gesture i would be using in every slide to perform functions.

I am working with V2 and Visual studio 2015 on windows 10.

Can someone please help me with the code as i am new to this.

I have already checked the plug ins. But i need to customize it for every slide so wouldn't really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is simple, i would check the shortcut keys in Powerpoint for the actions that you want, once you have them map the hand gestures to those keys so it would be like hitting the keyboard